# UITabBarController does not show "More" button

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using `MvxTabBarViewController` that is attributed with:

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
```

It does not present "More" button when I have more than five tabs added to the controller. Instead only the first four are shown.

The tabs are `MvxViewControllers` that are attributed with:

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxTabPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = false, TabIconName = "icon", TabName = "Tab 1")]
```

They are presented from `ViewWillAppear(bool animated)` method using `NavigationService.Navigate(TabOneViewModel)`

I tried setting `WrapInNavigationController` to `false`, but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a Storyboard, in order to add a TabBarController to your application you need to drag and drop a `UITabBarViewController` instead of a plain `UIViewController`. Otherwise some properties are not correctly derived (like the TabBar in this case - please see my screenshot).

Just make sure you delete the automatically created TabBar items!

[image: Screenshot showing UITabBarViewController in Interface Builder]

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know. Thank you!